# MS Visual Studio can't find Internet Explorer (developing an Outlook web add-in)

Tags: visual-studio, outlook-addin

I am trying to develop my first every Office add-in (for Outlook). Research shows that this should be a web-based add-in.

I create a new project (Outlook web add-in), and try to run it int the debugger & get an error "Unable to start debugging. Cannot locate Microsoft Internet Explorer".

I can't find any settings to change the default browser. What am I missing? Widows 10, Visual Studio 2017.

---

[Update] I will offer a good bonus (to be decided by the quality of the answer) for a solution, ***plus*** [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio) says " The add-in will be hosted locally on IIS" and I don't even know what that means :-(

Can someone explain how to set up the development environment for an Outlook web add-in? The coding itself seems straightforward, but I just can't get started because of the environment set-up.

Comment: Well, not so likely that you actually want to do this if you don't know what IIS means.  This add-in style applies to Office 365, the online document creation product from Microsoft that competes with Google Docs.  IIS is relevant because that is the web server product you need to run a web server to host the add-in.  All very different from the traditional way to create add-ins, a DLL that you distribute to users that run on the "normal" version of Office.

Comment: Thanks (+1). Yup, I know Apache, but not IIS. However, I do want to develop a Web Add-in for Outlook, so I will have to figure it out somehow :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sharad 's answer gave me a clue. I found that while `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer` existed, it did not contain `iexplore.exe`.

So, I went to [this page](https://www.techbout.com/install-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-12490/) and went to Install Internet Explorer on Windows 10 (It starts "In certain cases") and followed the instructions there.

That got Internet Explorer installed, and I can launch it by running `iexplore`.

Alas, now when I try to debug my Outlook web add-in, Visual Studio hangs, but that's a separate problem.

Comment: I'll get on that and try to help, what do you mean by "hangs"?

Comment: Well, it looks like it is trying to do something - probably launch the browser - after I enter my office 365 credentials; I am in the office now, but from memory the screen background changes, or it gains a colo(u)red border; it just looks like "I am busy now", but no browser or Outlook ever gets launched. I will post more later. I will ask a new question, with bounty, but am not sure which site. Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly open run and type **regedit**

Then navigate to:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

If the `iexplorer.exe` key is not there add it and change the (Default) REG_SZ value to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`.

Then add a new REG_SZ value and call it **Path** and set it to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer`

Then restart Visual Studio

I hope this helps!